# How to use "resulting" in the middle of the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The tap is leaking. The water is wasted.
>
> ____________________ resulting
> ___________________________.

Is this correct?

*The leaking tap resulting the wastage of water.*

Comment: The leaking tap is resulting in water wastage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess: ***The tap is leaking, resulting in water waste.***

- NOTE: I guess that it's ***tap*** (as in *a water tap*) rather than *tape*. The *tape* in your sentence could refer to some kind of *[seal tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_seal_tape)*, but if it really was seal tape, I'd expect the verb to be "torn off" or "broken", rather than "leaking".

The main point of your exercise seems to be about joining sentences by turning one of them into a [participle clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle). Because you're forced to use ***resulting***, the exercise seems to want you to know the phrasal verb ***[result in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/result-in)***.

The main pattern of *result in* is ***result in something***, which means that you have to turn the second sentence into a noun; which you did correctly as *wastage of water*, though I think *waste* is enough (*wastage* sounds a little too formal for me). You could use either *a waste of water* or simply use (like I choose to use) ***water waste***.

We now have a good enough background to convert the two sentences. Let's do it!

> Original: *The tap is leaking. The water is wasted.*
>
> Use 'result in', turn the idea into a noun:
>   *The tap is leaking. This **results in water waste**.*
>
> Join the two sentences by turning *result in* into *resulting in* (a participle):
>   *The tap is leaking, **resulting in** water waste.*

---

NOTE: *The leaking tap resulting (the) wastage of water* is not a sentence, even with ***resulting in***:

> Incorrect: *The leaking tap resulting in wastage of water.* **<-- DON'T USE IT!**

Why? Because the auxiliary verb is missing! If you want to phrase it that way, you need at least this:

*The leaking tap **is** resulting **in** wastage of water.*

Comment: _"The tap is leaking, resulting in water waste."_ Is comma necessary to make the sentence considered grammatically correct? *I don't seem to remember comma exists in the question...*

Comment: And _"water wastage"_ correct too?

Comment: a) "Is comma necessary to make the sentence considered grammatically correct?" -- Yes, you need a comma if you choose to join the sentence using the participle construction. (So, whether this construction is what your exercise and your teacher want or not would depend on the purpose of the exercise. In general, the more advanced the exercise is, the more possible alternatives we'll have, and the more advanced constructions we may use.); b) "And "water wastage" correct too?" -- Yes, you can use "water wastage" too.

Comment: It's national exam question. :P And is _water being wasted_ allowed too?

Comment: Oh! Practicing mind reading in addition to English would be a good idea, then. :D -- Yes, "resulting in water being wasted" is possible too.

Comment: I don't think auxiliary is needed. Would you elaborate it further?

Comment: @MaulikV Do you mean that you think "The leaking tap resulting in wastage of water." is correct?

Comment: If I did not think that, why would I *write* that as an answer? To me, [noun] resulting in [something] looks absolutely okay! @DamkerngT.

Comment: It's only okay as a noun phrase, @MaulikV. The OP's question is: "How to use “resulting” in the middle of the **sentence**?"

Comment: But then he *almost* made it: The leaking tap resulting the wastage of water. I just pointed out that he needs 'in' and it looks okay to me. Isn't it 'resulting' in the middle there?

Comment: @MaulikV In the middle of a "sentence"?

Comment: Is this correct too? _The tap, which is resulting in water being wasted, is leaking._

Comment: @XPMai I don't think it really works, or if it works, it's a rather awkward one (because the ideas come in the wrong order). Up to this point, I like this one the best: *The tap is leaking, resulting in water being wasted* (as you suggested *water being wasted* earlier). Or, as an alternative without a comma: *The leaking of the tap is resulting in water being wasted*.