# Use of "resulting in" with "and"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I have looked through [How to use "resulting" in the middle of the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69609/how-to-use-resulting-in-the-middle-of-the-sentence?newreg=a4ebc7eaf12b409d8fc694c12647ddc6) but still, am not sure how to use *resulting in*. My sentence is:

> Implemented version control using GIT and JUnit for testing the application, resulting in improvement of pre-production quality and reduction of post-production defect

My question is:  Is it correct? Also, can I write noun after *resulting in* as I have written *improvement* and *reduction*?

Comment: Is your sentence intended as a comment or a list item as in 

*• implemented X using Y*?

Comment: I want to use as a list item in bullet. I am writing this sentence for my resume.

Comment: The basic syntax is ***X resulted in Y*** (X *caused* Y), leading to ***X** [did something], **resulting in Y***. In your context you've "ungrammatically" omitted the subject (***I*** or ***we***, I suppose) so your basic structure is *We [implemented some things], **resulting in** [some improvements]*, which is fine. But it could just as well have been *We [did this], **which resulted in** [that]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay. So, is it true if I write like this? : I Implemented version control using GIT and JUnit for testing the application, resulting in improvement of pre-production quality and reduction of post-production defect.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Or you could use alternatives such as ***leading to, producing,*** etc. (that latter doesn't need a preposition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "to result in" is a **phrasal verb**, which is when verbs have prepositions (or adverbs) come after them to give them a new or different meaning (examples: *to take* and *to take off*; *to get* and *to get off*)

"to result in" is essentially a mix of "to cause" and "to happen", giving it the meaning "to cause something to happen"

*X did Y which resulted in Z* means the same as *X did Y which caused Y to happen*